# Must IO pins each have their own pull-up/down resistor?

Tags: resistors, pullup, pulldown

A very basic question:

Must each IO pin of a microcontroller that is serving as an input from a switch or jumper have its own pull-up/down resistor?

[image: Simple 3-pin IO schematic]

In this example, each pin is pulled down by a resistor, then pulled up by a 1P3T switch to VCC.

It seems straightforward, but as more IO pins are used, are more resistors absolutely required? Is there some clever way to keep the resistor count down?

*Related question: [Sharing a pull-up resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/37158/2028)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the schematic provided, if all 3 inputs were sharing a resistor, then any of the lines being pulled high via the switch would raise all 3 lines to high, countering the purpose of the design - the MCU would not know which switch position is selected.

A common way of reducing *part count*, not resistor count, for such designs is to use a common bus resistor network or array:
[image: Common Bus Resistor Array] *(from [here](http://www.samuraicircuits.com/MediaWiki/index.php?title=Doomsday_Clock_Shield_Resistor_Arrays))*

---

These are available as through-hole SIP/DIP as well as SMD, in a variety of resistor counts, depending on your needs. The bus pin is connected to ground, and the other pins are connected to the respective MCU inputs as in your schematic.
[image: SIP resistor arrays] *(from [here](http://www.diytrade.com/china/pd/1246051/MODEL_RN1082_RN1102_FILM_FIXED_RESISTOR_NETWORKS.html))*

[image: SMD resistor arrays] *(from [here](http://telecommunication.indiabizclub.com/catalog/468100~smd+chip+resistors+thick+film+network~shuk+tong+tsui))*

Answer (score 9):

Most MCUs have optional pull-up (not down) resistors built in for each pin, so it is normal to pull the pins DOWN with the switch (and deal with the polarity inversion in software).

So - no resistors necessary.

As to why pullup, not down, it's a habit left over from the 1970's TTL logic circuitry, where it took much less current to pull an input up than down - a pulldown resistor would waste more power. This no longer applies with today's CMOS logic, but the tradition of pull-ups has persisted, so that early 5V CMOS chips were compatible with older TTL logic.

Comment: I thought the reason for pull-up was because their common use was with open collector outputs, and once you're in the habit of going one way you'll keep going that way without a good reason.

Comment: Further, TTL outputs can sink 16mA but source only 800uA, so a pull-up might be used to add muscle to an output. A TTL input would pull itself up if you didn't connect it, so a pull-up for input reasons seems a bit strange to me. (Sorry, waited too long in editing the previous comment...)

Comment: "a TTL input would pull itself up" ... to some extent yes, but not reliably - the big orange book specifies a 40 microamp Ih to guarantee Vin > 2.4V (for 7400; 20ua for 74LS) Leaving TTL inputs open was definitely not recommended anywhere I worked...

Comment: Pulldowns versus pullups isn't merely historic.  With a pullup resistor, the other side of the switch can be ground, which is often convenient.

Comment: The TI MSP430 family of microcontrollers has both internal pull ups and pull downs.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to leave an input to logic open on the assumption that it would pull itself up or down.  if an input is left open, it is a little antenna and also subject to the currents within the logic device.  So you pull up or down to ensure you have a clean and predictable input.  I learned this rule while I worked at Fairchild Semiconductor in the 1980s.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: I think, the context of the original question is that there are buttons and switched that are inputs for an MCU.  If an I/O pin is unused, it can be made an output then driven low (or high) from firmware. That should address the lurking EMI issues, and it doesn't require an external resistor.